# Not able to call function when directive loads

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I'm working on AngularJS custom directive. I'm trying to call a function as soon as my directive loads.

I tried calling the function within link function, but it's throwing error as **TypeError: scope.setCurrent is not a function**.

Here's what I tried to do

```
function pagination() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'template/directives/pagination.html',
        scope: {
            totalData: '@',
        },
        link: dirPaginationControlsLinkFn
    };
}


function dirPaginationControlsLinkFn(scope, element, attrs){
    var vm = this;
    scope.setCurrent(1);    //this function is throwing error

    scope.setCurrent = function(num) {     //working fine
        scope.GetPager(scope.totalData,num,3);
    };
}
```

The same *setCurrent(data)* function is working fine when I'm triggering a click event

```html
<li ng-repeat="pages in pages track by $index">
  <a ng-click="setCurrent(pages)">{{ pages }}</a>
</li>
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is that you call function before declaration that is why setCurrent is not defined.

```
    scope.setCurrent = function(num) {     //first declare function and initialling with body 
        scope.GetPager(scope.totalData,num,3);
    };

    scope.setCurrent(1);    //than call function
```